# Eclipse IDE with tycho builder. Duplicated projects in Project explorer view

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tycho

I have maven project and I use Eclipse JDT for development. Project pom.xml files are generated by xtext framework. When loading project to eclipse I see parent folder (for example xxx.yyy.zzz.parent) that contains all subprojects. and the same subprojects once more again in the same level where parent is located.

- P1
- P2
- P3
- P4
- P.PARENT

  - P1
  - P2
  - P3
  - P4  -

Is this configuration error? Can I avoid duplicating?
I use Eclipse Neon.3 release

Answer (score 1):

this is normal behaviour. if you dont want to see the maven modules of the parent project you can click on the little arrow of the package explorer. filters. select maven modules